# Primitive group rings and endomorphism rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-rings, group-rings

It is known that, for any group $G$, there exists a group $H$ containing $G$ such that the group ring $F[H]$ for some field $F$ is primitive, see *Formanek, Edward; Snider, Robert L.*, [**Primitive group rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1972-0308178-8), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 36 (1972), 357-360 (1973). [ZBL0223.16007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0223.16007).

The group and faithful, simple module is constructed as follow:

$G_1 = G$, $M_1 = F[G_1]$

$G_2 = \textrm{Aut}_F(M_1)$, $M_2 = F[G_2] \oplus M_1$

and so on with $H = \bigcup G_i$ and $M = \bigcup M_i$.

We can consider $M$ both a left- and a right-module. Is it simple and faithful on both sides?

If so, then consider $\textrm{End}_{F[H]} M$ (where $M$ is a left-module) as it is left-simple we know that this is a division ring by Schur's lemma.
However, there is also a ring homomorphsim from $F[G]$ into $\textrm{End}_{F[H]} M$ by the action of right scalar multiplication.
And as $M$ is right-faithful, it has no non-zero annihilators and thus the homomorphsim is injective.

It seems, therefore, we have embedded $F[G]$ into a division ring?

Comment: Cool paper, by the way.  I wonder how far one can go replacing $F$ with something more general.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems, therefore, we have embedded [] into a division ring?

Well, you are probably asking because that is an absurdity, right? $F[G]$ can be chosen to have zero divisors.

It seems the proof claims only that $_{F[H]}M$ and $M_{F[H]}$ are simple and faithful. But the problem lies here:

> However, there is also a ring homomorphsim from [] into $End_{[]}$ by the action of right scalar multiplication.

This would be true if $M$ were an $F[H], F[H]$ bimodule (or even just an $F[H], F[G]$ bimodule) because then we're guaranteed that $(am)b=a(mb)$ , which says that the action of $F[G]$ on the right is left $F[H]$ linear.  The bimodule condition is not asserted and in light of the absurdity we could derive from it, is apparently false.

So I think that is the issue: you simply have an abelian group that is a simple module on both sides using two natural actions by the same ring: but not a fully fledged bimodule that would permit the embedding into a division ring.

Comment: Yes I agree it is absurd. Does the fact its a bimodule not follow from it being a left and right module?

Comment: Being a bimodule is a stronger condition than being both a left and a right module.  The condition $(am)b=a(mb)$  is not guaranteed.  As an example, $FG$ is a left $FG$-module via left multiplication.  But $G$ acts on the right of $FG$ by $a\odot g = g^{-1}a$ (which extends to a right $FG$-module structure).  But $h(a\odot g) = hg^{-1}a$ and $(ha)\odot g =g^{-1}ha$ and so unless $G$ is abelian, these actions don't give a bimodule.

Comment: Ahh I was imagining a different module structure where $G$ acts on $FG$ just by multiplication on the right

Comment: Right. Being a left and right module at the same time doesn't "link" the two actions with the condition you need to make your embedding work.

Comment: If it is just group multiplication then they are linked however by associativity of the underlying group

Comment: @EddieJones I'm not so sure.  Isn't part of the action applying group endomorphisms?  If you apply one on the left and one on the right, I don't think they're going to associate correctly.

Comment: Hmm that s a good point. I wonder though as the group changes throughout so it only ever really needs to act on itself (or at least a supergroup)

Comment: The same result (i.e. a group ring being primitive) can be achieved if we start with an algebraically closed group although it is not clear to me exactly what the module is in this case, see: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041578